# C++ Windows jumplist classes are not being identified

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, jump-list

Trying to build a softphone source (microsip) with Visual Studio 2008, but the windows jumplist classes are not being identified.

Line 19 gives an error because `ICustomDestinationList` is not being recognized

```
c:\users\gremblin\downloads\microsip-3.9.2-src\microsip-3.9.2-src\jumplist.h(19)
 : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'


 1. #ifndef jumplist_h__
 2. #define jumplist_h__
 3. 
 4. #include <string>
 5. #include <shobjidl.h>
 6. #include <propkey.h>
 7. #include <propvarutil.h>
 8. 
 9. class JumpList
10. {
11.  public:
12.   JumpList(std::wstring AppID);
13.   ~JumpList();
14.   bool DeleteJumpList();
15.   void AddTasks();
16.
17.  private:
18.   HRESULT _CreateShellLink(PCWSTR pszArguments, PCWSTR pszTitle, IShellLinkW **ppsl, int iconindex = -1);
19.   ICustomDestinationList *pcdl;
20. };

#endif // jumplist_h__
```

Am I missing something? As far as I know `jumplist` functions are all in `"shobjidl.h"`

Answer (score 1):

`shobjidl.h` defines `ICustomDestinationList` only when `NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN7`, so the compiler will complain if `NTDDI_VERSION` is not set to Windows 7 or higher.

`NTDDI_VERSION` is defined by default in `sdkddkver.h`:

```
#define NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT2(ver)    ver##0000
#define NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT(ver)     NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT2(ver)

...

#if !defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && !defined(_CHICAGO_)
#define  _WIN32_WINNT   0x0601
#endif

#ifndef NTDDI_VERSION
#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
// set NTDDI_VERSION based on _WIN32_WINNT
#define NTDDI_VERSION   NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT(_WIN32_WINNT)
#else
#define NTDDI_VERSION   0x06010000
#endif
#endif
```

So either define `NTDDI_VERSION` yourself in your project, or define `_WIN32_WINNT` to an appropriate value and let it propagate to `NTDDI_VERSION`.

Refer to MSDN for how `_WIN32_WINNT` relates to `NTDDI_VERSION`:

[Using Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx)