# Task bar "Frequent" and "Tasks" - How to add

Tags: windows

I notice that certain apps, Firefox among them, present task bar choices when right clicked.  In the case of Firefox these are sites recently visited under the heading "frequent" and some file menu choices under the heading "tasks".

My question is how does one add these items?  What system call is used?

Comment: Search SO for `jumplist` to find examples. You didn't say which programming language, so it's not clear which example works best for you. I chose C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Windows jumplist classes are not being identified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412405/c-windows-jumplist-classes-are-not-being-identified)